# MySQL sharding approaches?

Tags: mysql, sharding

What is the best approach for Sharding MySQL tables.
The approaches I can think of are :

1. Application Level sharding?
2. Sharding at MySQL proxy layer?
3. Central lookup server for sharding?

Do you know of any interesting projects or tools in this area?

Answer (score 130):

The best approach for sharding MySQL tables to not do it unless it is totally unavoidable to do it.

When you are writing an application, you usually want to do so in a way that maximizes velocity, developer speed. You optimize for latency (time until the answer is ready) or throughput (number of answers per time unit) only when necessary.

You partition and then assign partitions to different hosts (= shard) only when the sum of all these partitions does no longer fit onto a single database server instance - the reason for that being either writes or reads.

The write case is either a) the frequency of writes is overloading this servers disks permanently or b) there are too many writes going on so that replication permanently lags in this replication hierarchy.

The read case for sharding is when the size of the data is so large that the working set of it no longer fits into memory and data reads start hitting the disk instead of being served from memory most of the time.

Only when you **have** to shard you do it.

---

The moment you shard, you are paying for that in multiple ways:

Much of your SQL is no longer declarative.

Normally, in SQL you are telling the database what data you want and leave it to the optimizer to turn that specification into a data access program. That is a good thing, because it is flexible, and because writing these data access programs is boring work that harms velocity.

With a sharded environment you are probably joining a table on node A against data on node B, or you have a table larger than a node, on nodes A and B and are joining data from it against data that is on node B and C. You are starting to write application side hash-based join resolutions manually in order to resolve that (or you are reinventing MySQL cluster), meaning you end up with a lot of SQL that no longer declarative, but is expressing SQL functionality in a procedural way (e.g. you are using SELECT statements in loops).

You are incurring a lot of network latency.

Normally, an SQL query can be resolved locally and the optimizer knows about the costs associated with local disk accesses and resolves the query in a way that minimizes the costs for that.

In a sharded environment, queries are resolved by either running key-value accesses across a network to multiple nodes (hopefully with batched key accesses and not individual key lookups per round trip) or by pushing parts of the `WHERE` clause onward to the nodes where they can be applied (that is called 'condition pushdown'), or both.

But even in the best of cases this involves many more network round trips that a local situation, and it is more complicated. Especially since the MySQL optimizer knows nothing about network latency at all (Ok, MySQL cluster is slowly getting better at that, but for vanilla MySQL outside of cluster that is still true).

You are losing a lot of expressive power of SQL.

Ok, that is probably less important, but foreign key constraints and other SQL mechanisms for data integrity are incapable of spanning multiple shards.

MySQL has no API which allows asynchronous queries that is in working order.

When data of the same type resides on multiple nodes (e.g. user data on nodes A, B and C), horizontal queries often need to be resolved against all of these nodes ("Find all user accounts that have not been logged in for 90 days or more"). Data access time grows linearly with the number of nodes, unless multiple nodes can be asked in parallel and the results aggregated as they come in ("Map-Reduce").

The precondition for that is an asynchronous communication API, which does not exist for MySQL in a good working shape. The alternative is a lot of forking and connections in the child processes, which is visiting the world of suck on a season pass.

---

Once you start sharding, data structure and network topology become visible as performance points to your application. In order to perform reasonably well, your application needs to be aware of these things, and that means that really only application level sharding makes sense.

The question is more if you want to auto-shard (determining which row goes into which node by hashing primary keys for example) or if you want to split functionally in a manual way ("The tables related to the xyz user story go to this master, while abc and def related tables go to that master").

Functional sharding has the advantage that, if done right, it is invisible to most developers most of the time, because all tables related to their user story will be available locally. That allows them to still benefit from declarative SQL as long as possible, and will also incur less network latency because the number of cross-network transfers is kept minimal.

Functional sharding has the disadvantage that it does not allow for any single table to be larger than one instance, and it requires manual attention of a designer.

Functional sharding has the advantage that it is relatively easily done to an existing codebase with a number of changes that is not overly large. http://Booking.com has done it multiple times in the past years and it worked well for them.

---

Having said all that, looking at your question, I do believe that you are asking the wrong questions, or I am completely misunderstanding your problem statement.

Comment: This is a good answer. But I want to point out that sharding is really only needed for high volume applications and chances are they are generating some kind of revenue. A third party sharding application will handle all the concerns you have with joins, cross-shard transactions, etc. And if you get a good one, it will maintain the integrity of a "relational" database. Other applications, you are right, will simple turn your database into a key-value pair and thus defeat the purpose of SQL.

Comment: I have yet to come across a sharding application, commercial or not, that is successful in hiding the fact that the data is now scattered across the network and subject to latency or inconsistency due to the lack of latency-induced waits. If you are sharding, you application is going to notice and will require changes. You might as well be in control of that yourself. There is no silver bullet, but there is a lot of snake oil.

Comment: You should check out dbShards. It scales better than linearly per the # of "shards" you add. You will require very little, if any, changes on the application side, and yes you application does not know the difference. It just sends and get transactions the same as you would with ODBC or JDBC. dbShards also allows shard-hints if you want more control over a transaction. You can tell dbShards exactly what shard you want to read or write from.

Comment: @Gigala well, spending time composing a well-defined answer like this, regardless of broadness, isn't necessary either, but I'm glad it was done, as this answer has proven helpful for me. Please don't discourage users to not "think outside the box" when answering.

Comment: This answer is now 10 years old. Things have happened.

You may want to have a look at TiDB from https://en.pingcap.com/ and at https://vitess.io/. But provide relatively good general answers to the question.

TiDB is a reimplementation of a database that speaks MySQL protocol. vitess is build on (an outdated) version of MySQL plus additional code. They are very different, but count as solutions to the original question.

Answer (score 13):

1. Application Level sharding: dbShards is the only product that I know of that does "application aware sharding". There are a few good articles on the website. Just by definition, application aware sharding is going to be more efficient. If an application knows exactly where to go with a transaction without having to look it up or get redirected by a proxy, that in its self will be faster. And speed is often one of the primary concerns, if not the only concern, when someone is looking into sharding.
2. Some people "shard" with a proxy, but in my eyes that defeats the purpose of sharding. You are just using another server to tell your transactions where to find the data or where to store it. With application aware sharding, your application knows where to go on its own. Much more efficient.
3. This is the same as #2 really.

Comment: is dbShards in use in production some where? also it is not open source.

Comment: Also approach 2 and 3 can be different if the proxy looks up based on a hash instead of the DB or a store.

Comment: dbShards is in production with a variety of clients, but no, it is not open source. I don't think you will find a good open source sharding product. And yes you are correct that a hash could be used as a lookup, but in that case you are still having to take one more "stop" in order to get your transaction to the database. That is why "application aware" sharding will almost always be faster.

Comment: But like I said, if you can get a sharding application that maintains the integrity of relationships, then you will be in good shape. I mention dbShards because it is the only one I know of that does. And since it does, it scales your write and read speeds linearly. You add 4 "shards" or you split your one MySQL server into 4 and it will run 4 times as fast.

Answer (score 7):

> Do you know of any interesting projects or tools in this area?

Several new projects in this space:

- [citusdata.com](http://citusdata.com)
- spockproxy.sourceforge.net
- <s>github.com/twitter/gizzard/</s>

Answer (score 6):

Application level of course.

Best approach I've ever red I've found in this book

High Performance MySQL 
[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Jeremy-Zawodny/dp/0596003064](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003064)

Short description: you could split your data in many parts and store ~50 part on each server. It will help you to avoid the second biggest problem of sharding - rebalancing. Just move some of them to the new server and everything will be fine :)

I strongly recommend you to buy it and read "mysql scaling" part.

Comment: The book you recommended is 8 years old...does it covers sharding relevant to today's technologies?

Comment: It covers some basic approaches to scale mysql. AFAIK nothing changed in scaling mysql. Same app-level sharding and replication techniques are widely used nowdays.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I've been doing a ton of research on this over the past week and it looks like mySQL itself has made a lot of changes in the last 8 years, especially regarding partitioning and caching. There is a new version that came out this year : http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/1449314287/ref=dp_ob_title_bk/185-6821409-4526615 I haven't read it but I think it covers the new replication models available.

Comment: Books.. why not just explain it here.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2018, there seems to be a MySql-native solution to that. There are actually at least 2 - [InnoDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-userguide.html) and [NDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster.html)(there is a commercial and a community version of it).

Since most people who use MySql community edition are more familiar with InnoDB engine, this is what should be explored as a first priority. It supports replication and partitioning/sharding out of the box and is based on MySql Router for different routing/load-balancing options.

The syntax for your tables creation would need to change, for example:

```
    CREATE TABLE t1 (col1 INT, col2 CHAR(5), col3 DATETIME) PARTITION BY HASH ( YEAR(col3) );
```

(this is only one of four [partitioning types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-types.html))

One very important limitation:

> InnoDB foreign keys and MySQL partitioning are not compatible. Partitioned InnoDB tables cannot have foreign key references, nor can they have columns referenced by foreign keys. InnoDB tables which have or which are referenced by foreign keys cannot be partitioned.

Comment: Be aware that `PARTITION BY HASH(YEAR...)` will scan _all_ partitions if you have a date range.  Yuck.

Answer (score 5):

[Shard-Query](http://code.google.com/p/shard-query) is an OLAP based sharding solution for MySQL.  It allows you to define a combination of sharded tables and unsharded tables.  The unsharded tables (like lookup tables) are freely joinable to sharded tables, and sharded tables may be joined to each other as long as the tables are joined by the shard key (no cross shard or self joins that cross shard boundaries).  Being an OLAP solution, Shard-Query usually has minimum response times of 100ms or less, even for simple queries so it will not work for OLTP.  Shard-Query is designed for analyzing big data sets in parallel.

OLTP sharding solutions exist for MySQL as well.  Closed source solutions include [ScaleDB](http://scaledb.com), [DBShards](http://www.codefutures.com/dbshards).  Open source OLTP solution include [JetPants](https://github.com/tumblr/jetpants), [Cubrid](http://cubrid.org) or [Flock/Gizzard](https://github.com/twitter/gizzard) (Twitter infrastructure).

Answer (score 3):

> Do you know of any interesting projects or tools in this area?

As of 2022 Here are 2 tools:

- Vitess (website: https://vitess.io & repo: https://github.com/vitessio/vitess)
- PlanetScale (https://planetscale.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this middleware
[shardingsphere](https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere)